# React Typescript: Antd Table filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I am getting an error in the columns when I try the following:

```
{
   title: "Gruppe",
   dataIndex: 'group',
   filters: [
      this.state.dropdownItems.map((item) => ({
         text: item.group,
         value: item.group
      })
   )],
   onFilter: (value, record) => record.TransactionType.includes(value),
},
```

> Error: *TS2322    (TS) Type '({ title: string; dataIndex: string; key:
> string; width: number; align: "center"; sorter: (a: any, b: any) =>
> number; filters?: undefined; onFilter?: undefined; render?: undefined;
> } | { title: string; ... 7 more ...; render?: undefined; } | { ...; }
> | { ...; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type
> 'ColumnsType'.   Type '{ title: string;
> dataIndex: string; key: string; width: number; align: "center";
> sorter: (a: any, b: any) => number; filters?: undefined; onFilter?:
> undefined; render?: undefined; } | { title: string; ... 7 more ...;
> render?: undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not
> assignable to type 'ColumnGroupType |
> ColumnType'.
> Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; width: number; align: "center"; filters: { text: string; value: string; }[][]; onFilter:
> (value: any, record: any) => any; key?: undefined; sorter?: undefined;
> render?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type
> 'ColumnGroupType |
> ColumnType'.
> Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; width: number; align: "center"; filters: { text: string; value: string; }[][]; onFilter:
> (value: any, record: any) => any; key?: undefined; sorter?: undefined;
> render?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type
> 'ColumnType'.
> Types of property 'filters' are incompatible.
> Type '{ text: string; value: string; }[][]' is not assignable to type 'ColumnFilterItem[]'.
> Type '{ text: string; value: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ColumnFilterItem': text, value   *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `map` returns a new array, so now you are defining an 2 dimensional array as filters, it should be like this:

```
filters: [
  ...this.state.dropdownItems.map((item) => ({
     text: item.group,
     value: item.group
  })
)]
```

Or:

```
filters: this.state.dropdownItems.map((item) => ({
     text: item.group,
     value: item.group
  })
)
```